# Python: Merging lists with lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
packets=[['B', 'A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E'], ['D', 'E'], []]
```

I have two for loops on the same list something like:

```
for a in packets[:]:
   for b in packets[:]:
```

i.e., each time `a=['B','A']` `b` iterates from `['B','A']` all the way to `['D','E']`. This is what I want to do:

If the last element of `a` is equal to the first element of `b` i.e., when `a=['B','A']` and `b=['A','D']` I must have `['B','A','D']`. Again the last element of `['B','A','D']` is equal to the first element of `['D','E']`. So, now I must have `['B','C','D','E']`.

Similarly, when `A=['B','C']` and `b=['C','E']` I must have `['B','C','E']`. When `A=['B','C']` and `b=['C','D']` and `b=['D','E']` I must have `['B','C','D','E']` and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `[]` element at the end? You don't need a sentinel for iteration in Python, because the list knows its own length.

Comment: If you have any code already written, you should post it (and make sure to format it as code).  Also, do you mean ['B','A','D','E'] the first time?

Comment: What if you have [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'D']]? Do you want both ['A', 'B', 'C'] and ['A', 'B', 'D'] in the output? What if there is a cycle, such as [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A']]?

Comment: What does it mean to "have" something? Store it in another list? Store it in the same list?

Comment: @senderle yes I think the OP means "merge adjacent lists if `list1.end == list2.start`, then replace `list1, list2` with the merged list"

Comment: @siva, it all doesn't sound very Pythonic, can you tell us more about the intent of these data structures? Do you care more about scalability or simplicity of code - are you handling 10 or 1,000,000 elements? How many distinct values can the elements typically take on?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but

```
>>> packets=[['B', 'A'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E'], ['D', 'E'], []]
>>> 
>>> for a in packets:
...     for b in packets:
...         if a and b and a[-1]==b[0]:
...             print a[:-1]+b
...             packets.append(a[:-1]+b)
... 
['B', 'A', 'D']
['B', 'C', 'D']
['B', 'C', 'E']
['A', 'D', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'E']
['B', 'A', 'D', 'E']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: One thing I'm not sure of in this answer is the repetition of `['B', 'A', 'D']` in `['B', 'A', 'D', 'E']` and similar cases.  And from the odd word choice in the question, it's very difficult to tell whether or not that's desired.  Also, this assumes no loops exist in the list - otherwise you're stuck in an infinite loop (try `packets = [['B','A'],['A','B']]`.  Though once again, no way of knowing from the question if that's a problem.

Comment: @Jodaka, As you say, the question leaves out a lot of details. I suspect that a graph/tree would better model these data